# Run kriging in ModelBuilder with various shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator, kriging, z-value

I need to run kriging in a model, using 5 different point shapefiles. I put as input `%Name%` to run the different shapefiles, but in Z value field I have an error, because it's different in each shapefile.

So, how do I run kriging through various shapefiles that have different Z value fields? I want 5 output rasters. I'm doing this:

[image]

Comment: Will the individual database schema of the shapefiles change over time?

Comment: How, exactly, does the Z field differ from one shapefile to the next?

Comment: Z field has different name and content from one shapefile to the next.

Comment: Andreia, What is the name of Z fields? do they follow a pattern? e.g. Z_Field1,Z_Field2,....

Comment: No, they don't follow a pattern. They are: comp_u, comp_v, temp, t_orv

Comment: You could add and calculate a new field 'Z' for each input.  That can easily be added to the beginning of your model.